# Indent or not based on section depth

Tags: sectioning, indentation, memoir

I would like to know how to set it up so that a `\subsubsection{}` will indent the first paragraph but all other sectioning command of a higher level (`\chapter{}`, `\section{}`, and `\subsection{}`) will NOT indent the first paragraph.

To be clear, I don't want to use the `indentfirst` package because that makes all section levels indented.

I am using the `memoir` class, should that be somehow important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer turns out to be quite easy: add the following trick to your preamble

```
\setlength{\beforesubsubsecskip}{-\beforesubsubsecskip}
```

If the length represented by `\beforesubsubsecskip` is negative, the spacing will be the same as when it's positive, but the first paragraph following a `\subsubsection` command will be indented (the default value is positive).

Comment: Oh my, that worked nicely.